# Force chat style scrolling to bottom of element when calling new data

Tags: html, angular, scroll

Alright, Ive been trying things for about 2 weeks now and cant seem to get a solution to my problem here. In essence, the thing Im trying to fix is within the chat window of my angular site. A user can post a message, and after posting a message, the chat window should scroll the chat element to the bottom so the new message is visible.

The problem then, is that while I can get it to scroll, I cannot seem to get it to scroll past the new message, and at most, it scrolls down to the next-to-last message, as if it doesnt realize a new element is needed to scroll past.

Thing Ive tried:
Ive tried ngAfterViewInit for a solution, though the problem there lies in the fact that Im using material design for buttons, and simply scrolling over buttons with tooltips in the component causes this to trigger, forcing the scrolldown at unwanted times.
Ive tried ngOnChanges, which recognizes the change of messages, though even thought it can recognize it, setting the logic to recognize this change still doesnt force the window past the second to last message

As for the code, this is the syntax that posts a new message, which calls upon the method within a viewchild component (being the chat window) to scroll down to the bottom AFTER the message has been posted.

```
  public async send(messageResponse: MessageApiResponse)
  {
    this.postingMessage = true;

    await this.SantaApiPost.postMessage(messageResponse).toPromise();
    await this.profileService.getSelectedHistory(this.profile.clientID, this.selectedHistory.relationXrefID, true);

    this.chatComponent.scrollToBottom();

    this.postingMessage = false;
  }
```

And the method in the child that it calls upon, just for reference

```
  public scrollToBottom(): void {
    try {
        this.chatFrame.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.chatFrame.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    } catch(err) { }
  }
```

Posting posts the message, and the next line refreshes the chat history, which itself is a promise, not a subscribe, so things shouldn't be out of order there. Once this is done, it should scroll the chat from the viewchild, but it doesnt do it fully, and I cant for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong here, or how that can be remedied. [Demo of failing functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQnc9.gif)

Comment: Does wrapping your `scrollToBottom` function in a setTimeout help? e.g. `setTimeout(() => this.chatComponent.scrollToBottom(), 0)`

Comment: That actually works wonderfully! Ive never hard of that before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you `await` for a new message to be posted the scroll to the bottom function executes before the DOM rendering of that message. So the code is actually doing its job, it's just firing a little too early.

`setTimeout(callback, 0)` corrects that behaviour by adding a new event to a browsers event queue. Therefore, allowing the DOM manipulation (adding of a new message) to complete before calling the scroll to bottom function.